# Are there pairs of matrices whose nested commutators don't vanish?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

So I've been reading up on Lie Groups and Lie Algebras and the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. I understand how the formula works and that most of the time the nested commutators vanish at a certain point, but I'm wondering if there exist pairs of matrices whose nested commutators never vanish and what they'd look like.

I can't find anything on the subject and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: It's certainly *not* true that "most of the time the nested commutators vanish." This is only true in the simplest cases, e.g. for nilpotent Lie algebras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure: In $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$, the usual basis elements $e, f, h$ satisfy
\begin{align*}
[e, f] &= h & [h, e] &= 2e & [h, f] &= 2f.
\end{align*}
Thus the $k$-fold nested commutator $[h, [h, \dots, [h, f] \cdots ]] = 2^k f$ is nonzero for all $k > 0$. More generally, the condition that every $k$-fold nested commutator vanishes for some *fixed* $k$ (i.e., not depending on the elements in that commutator) is called nilpotency.

Comment: Ah, I only thought of nilpotency in terms of a single matrix with a power that brings it to zero. Anyhow, thanks for the answer!